# Image alligned not set in Center using FrameLayout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-framelayout

I'm trying to learn `FrameLayout`  from this `tutorial`

http://javatechig.com/android/android-framelayout-example

it adds one `imageView` in `FrameLayout` and trying the image to be in center with

```
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

but it's not working 
Image shows like this

[image]

here is activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        </FrameLayout>
```

here is class file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

is it some new attribute that need to be replaced ??
Image aligns well in relative layout but not in frame layout.Any suggestion ?

Comment: use layout_gravity="center" in your imageview

Comment: scaleType is only meant to determine how to scale the bitmap inside the imageView itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set layout gravity to imageView.

```
 android:layout_gravity="center"
```

depends on your requirment you can give "layout_gravity" like:

```
center_vertical or center_horizontal.
```

Answer (score 2):

@user3734952 :FYI

**`android:layout_gravity="center"`**

Is a Layout Param. Not all View Groups support this Layout Param. See the documentation to find out which Layout Params are supported by a particular View Group. Linear Layout does support `android:layout_gravity` Layout Param.Place the object in the center of its container in both the vertical and horizontal axis, not changing its size.

For better approach please please add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`.Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.

Answer (score 1):

`scaleType` is not mean the way image place in its father layout, but how to place the image inside its own boarder layout. see [ScaleType link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

If you want to adjust the alignment like left , bottom or center, you can use `android:layout_gravity` in the ImageView or set `android:gravity` in it's father layout.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```